# react native elements tabs style

Tags: react-native, react-native-elements

I need some styling help cause I can't change it :) I know it sounds ridiculous but here we are

so this is my code and screenshot of it. please tell me which style changes this purple border under the tab name

```
<Tab value={tabIndex} onChange={setTabIndex} >
        <Tab.Item
          title="PORTFÖY"
        />
        <Tab.Item
          title="GAYRİMENKUL"
        />
      </Tab>
      <TabView value={tabIndex} onChange={setTabIndex}>
        <TabView.Item style={{width: '100%'}}>
          {isLoadingPortfoy ? (
            <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#0f0" />
          ) : (
            portfoy()
          )}
        </TabView.Item>
        <TabView.Item style={{width: '100%'}}>
          {isLoadingMulk ? (
            <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#0f0" />
          ) : (
            mulk()
          )}
        </TabView.Item>
      </TabView>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Material UI, this will work for you

```
<Tabs TabIndicatorProps={{style: {background:'ANY_COLOR'}}}>
```

or

```
<Tabs inkBarStyle={{background: 'blue'}}>
```

Comment: thanks for the help <Tab disableIndicator={true}/> would do the same work for me :)